Why I got error on reading data from array in blade file?
In laravel 11 / livewire 3 / app I added laravel/scout: ^10.11 and read data from $meiliSearch as:
    $this->dataFromMLS = Article::search($this->search, function(, string $query, array $options ) {
        $options['attributesToHighlight'] = ['title', 'text', 'text_shortly'];
        return $meiliSearch->search($query, $options);
    })
     ->paginateRaw(10)->items();

when I output these data in blade file with code :
{{ var_dump($dataFromMLS);  }}

I see array outputted :

and

I got error :
Undefined array key "hits"

pointing to line :
dataFromMLS['hits'] ::{{ print_r($dataFromMLS['hits'], true) }}<hr>

and I can not see why error? From component I got array data and in my printscreen there is an array with 7 elements...

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

Who uses var_dump in laravel when you have powerful helper function called dd?

Looks like after I manually deleted 'storage/framework/views/' subdirectory - I have no this error any more. Do not know, why ?

Hard to tell to be honest. It sounds unrelated to this. Unless an old copy of the code was being cached there or something

Deleting storage/framework/views indicates an old version of the view was cached, which could mean that the view contained incorrect data. But hard to tell.
